# Validar caja de texto para que primer caracter sea letra C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un formulario en C# Forms, donde me piden validar el código de un usuario que debe empezar con una letra continuado de 9 números. ¿Cómo puedo validar esa cadena?

```
string codigo = txtCodigo.Text;
string primer = codigo.Substring(0);
string segundo = codigo.Substring(1);
int conversegundo = (int)Int64.Parse(segundo);

//para validar si es número o letra (true para número y false para letra)
int n;
bool validarprimer = int.TryParse(primer, out n);

if (validarprimer == false) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ingrese un código de alumno válido");
}

if(conversegundo <= 999999999 && conversegundo > 99999999) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ingrese un código de alumno válido");
}
```

Comment: Prueba utilizando una expresión regular por ejemplo: @"^[A-Za-z][0-9]{9}$"

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que validar 3 cosas:

- El largo debe ser igual a 10 (1 letra + 9 números)
- El 1er caracter es una letra, usas `char.IsLetter`
- El resto lo obtienes usando rangos `[1..]` lo cual es igual a decir desde la posición 1 (el 2do caracter, ya que se comienza desde el cero) hasta el final
- Luego ese resto final debe ser un número

Entonces creas una función con esas condiciones, quedando algo así:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(IsValidCode("A123456789"));  // True
    Console.WriteLine(IsValidCode("Z000000001"));  // True
    Console.WriteLine(IsValidCode("A12345678"));   // False -> largo 9
    Console.WriteLine(IsValidCode("AB13456789"));  // False -> Los últimos 9 no son todos números
    Console.WriteLine(IsValidCode("1234567890"));  // False -> El 1er carácter no es letra
    Console.WriteLine(IsValidCode(""));            // False -> largo menor que 10
}

public static bool IsValidCode(string code)
=> code.Length == 10 && char.IsLetter(code[0]) && int.TryParse(code[1..], out _);
```